# No puedo usar Keras-Tuner para LSTM

Tags: keras, lstm

Espero puedan ayudarme. Estoy usando Keras-Tuner RandomSearch y cuando quiero iniciar la búsqueda de hiperparámetros en una arquitectura LSTM me sale el siguiente error:

> Error:
> "TypeError: add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'return_sequences'"

```
    from keras_tuner.tuners import RandomSearc

    def build_model(hp):
        model = Sequential()
        
        model.add(LSTM(units = hp.Int('input_units', min_value = 32, max_value = 512, step= 32), activation='relu'), return_sequences=True, activation='relu', input_shape=(30,126))

        for i in range(hp.Int('layers_LSTM', 1,6)):
            model.add(LSTM(units = hp.Int(f'lstm_{i}_units', min_value = 32,
                                          max_value = 512,
                                          step= 32), activation='relu'), return_sequences=True, 

        model.add(Dense(actions.shape[0], activation='softmax'))

        return model

    tuner = RandomSearch(
        build_model,
        objective='val_categorical_accuracy',
        max_trials=5,
        executions_per_trial = 1)

    tuner.search(X_train, y_train, epochs=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
    best_model = tuner.get_best_models()[0]
```

Saben que puede estar pasando?

Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]!  Tu pregunta no está en el idioma oficial del sitio. Puedes traducirla pulsando sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece a pie de pregunta, gracias.

Comment: Ese parámetro `return_sequences` entendería que es del LSTM y tú se lo estás entregando al `Sequential.add()`. Problema de paréntesis :P

Comment: fue un tema de paréntesis.
Gracias!